# How do I store multiple values into an array to be printed out later?

Tags: c++

Ok so here I am going to insert the code of this program I am developing to help me with work. I don't want to go into too much detail on how it is used, but the bottom line is that I am creating a program that: takes the two values from the user, manipulates them, and then stores them into an array.

Now I can do that with a very simple linear program, but where i am having difficult time is that when the program starts it asks the user to enter two values, the program then stores it, then as it loops again, it will ask the user for two more values, then I want it to be stored again, the amount of times stored depends on the amount of data points the user needs, then in the end i want it to print out all the manipulated values they entered, in the end i want it to export it to a txt file, but that will come later. I just want to get the basic down. Can anyone help me with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

double dCoordinates(double x)
{
    return x / 1000;
}

void Store(int x , int y)
{
    int anCoorValues[] = { x, y };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many data points do you need to enter?" << std::endl;
    int nAmountOfDataPoints;
    std::cin >> nAmountOfDataPoints;

    for (int nCount = 0; nCount < nAmountOfDataPoints; nCount++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter E/W Coordinates" << std::endl;
        double dEW;
        std::cin >> dEW;

        std::cout << "Enter N/S Coordinates" << std::endl;
        double dNS;
        std::cin >> dNS;

        Store(dCoordinates(dEW),dCoordinates(dNS));
    }
}
```

Comment: don't mix tabs and spaces for indenting here, just use 4 spaces per indent level.

Comment: I think you want a `vector<double>` with two pushes or `vector<std::pair<double, double> >` with a `push_back` of `std::make_pair`.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a container in main and then pass it to other functions as a parameter if you need to do so. Then in any time you can output the container. In your case it is better to use `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>`

For example (By the way why does function Store have parameters of type int?)

```
#include <vector>
#includde <utility>

double dCoordinates( double x )
{
    return x / 1000;
}

void Store( std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> &v, double x , double y )
{
    v.push_back( { x, y } );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many data points do you need to enter?" << std::endl;
    int nAmountOfDataPoints;
    std::cin >> nAmountOfDataPoints;

    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> v;
    v.reserve( nAmountOfDataPoints ) ;

    //...
    // Here you can output the folled vector

    for ( const std::pair<double, double> &p : v )
    {
        std::cout << "( " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " )" << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code:

```
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <vector>    // std::vector
#include <utility>   // std::pair, std::make_pair()
#include <algorithm> // std::for_each()

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double> > entered_values;

    std::cout << "How many data points do you need to enter?" << std::endl;
    int nAmountOfDataPoints;
    std::cin >> nAmountOfDataPoints;

    entered_values.reserve(nAmountOfDataPoints);


    for (int nCount = 0; nCount < nAmountOfDataPoints; ++nCount)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter E/W Coordinates" << std::endl;
        double dEW;
        std::cin >> dEW;

        std::cout << "Enter N/S Coordinates" << std::endl;
        double dNS;
        std::cin >> dNS;

        entered_values.push_back(std::make_pair(dEW, dNS));
    }

    std::for_each(std::begin(entered_values), std::end(entered_values), [] (std::pair<double, double> const &i) {std::cout << i.first << "," << i.second << std::endl;});
}
```